# Facebook not reading my OpenGraph on some pages

Tags: facebook, blogs, facebook-opengraph

I own a Facebook page here:

facebook.com/moonward

And everytime I post a new article on my blog I paste the url in the status and it usually picks up the OpenGraph correctly, but sometimes with some urls it fails horribly.

For example, this doesn't work:

http://www.moonward.net/inspiracion/2012/01/guy-laramee-esculturas-de-libros/

And this one does:

http://www.moonward.net/animacion/2011/12/diablo-iii-impresionante-video-introduccion-y-arte/

What's the difference? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the blogging engine or the hosting of that blog is very slow to respond.

Facebook's linter cannot get a response in a timely manner and give up.

> **Scrape Information** 
>   Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.

Try for yourself:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.moonward.net%2Finspiracion%2F2012%2F01%2Fguy-laramee-esculturas-de-libros%2F

**EDIT**

There are so many things that can cause the interwebs to be slow.  Let's start at the content and list some of the points where the process can be slow.  Remember, it may even be a combination of these issues, it doesn't have to be just one.

- The db is slow in returning data to the blog engine.
- The connection between the db and server is overloaded
- The blog engine is overloaded and cannot process the response/request from the db
- The blog engine is slow parsing that data to present as HTML
- the web server is slow sending out the HTML to the client
- the network between the webserver and firewall is overloaded
- the firewall is overloaded
- the interwebs are overloaded at some point in the tracert between the user and webserver.

Comment: It's really weird, since it works good with some other posts. Shouldn't this happen to all posts if it's a server issue?

Comment: But I still don't see how it can work for some posts and not for others. If it was a DB or host speed issue it will happen for every single post, and not just for some of them...

The randomness of this issue is killing me, and in fact other Social Media like Google Plus or Twitter don't have this problem at all and respond perfectly...